# websockets javascript mapbox

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, mapbox

Relativity new to code and find that I learn most from muscling through a problems but need some pointers.

My project has two parts.  A responsive map that deep dives into communities (this is being built by the team) and a second map that displays the map in fullscreen with markers that appear and disappear to display activity as users click into each community.  I have the second map on my own server. The production map will need to pass a Lat,Long object [I've figured out how to collect these coordinates].

1) I believe I'll need a websocket to connect the two.  Could anyone pass along specific examples with how to connect the two that passes an object?

2) After I have the Lat,Long object on the server, how do I pass it from my websocket app into my javascript file? OR do I make my javascript file LISTEN for a new instance of a message?

Thank you!

Comment: Simple crisp questions are enjoyed by all ... Please rephrase to state the essence

Comment: How about using AJAX?

Comment: Is your server side nodejs ?

Comment: Yes - nodejs on the server.  I found this [link - Websocket Basics](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/).  It explains that I can use the callback function to receive the input.  Does this mean that the websocket needs to be opened in the my main app.js file and then I'll just assign it to a variable to be passed into the function I have already created?

Comment: @ScottStensland = Thanks for the advice.  I'll try to be more concise in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Websockets are inherently two directional once activated ... that is traffic can be initiated from either side
... once opened up a websocket connection is persistent so stays open even when not dealing with traffic

Here is the entire nodejs code to define a WebSocket server side

```
var websocker_server = function() {

    "use strict";

    var port = 8888;

    console.log('listening on    localhost:' + port + '\n');

    var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

    var wss = new WebSocketServer({ port: port });

    wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {

        ws.send('this message was sent from server side to client');


        ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
        console.log('received: %s', message);
        });

        // ---

        ws.on("error", function(event) {

            var error_msg = "ERROR on on on error : " + event;
            console.error(error_msg);
        });

        // ---

        ws.on("close", function() {

            console.log("websocket connection close");
        });

    });

}(); //  websocker_server = function()
```

So now I show the entire html with inline javascript which defines a bare bones browser side WebSocket client

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>bare bones websocket with nodejs serverside</title>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var websocket_connection = (function() {

        var web_socket = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888');

        web_socket.onopen = function (event) {

          web_socket.send("Here's some text client has sent to server upon socket open event!"); 
        };

        web_socket.onmessage = function (event) {
          console.log(event.data);
        }

    }());   //   websocket_connection

</script>

</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The big picture is first launch the nodejs server side which listens on port 8888 ... then run the html from a httpd server so you can point your browser at its code ... the browser client initiates the WebSocket connection which once opened up then permits messages to be sent in either direction ...  I suggest you first get this working using text format messages as outlined here and if desired possibly use JSON format if your messages start getting complex

[I posted all this code and supporting instructions as a repo HERE](https://github.com/scottstensland/websocket-simpleapp)